# RegEx - find and replace content between two tag which is at multiple location in same file

Tags: java

I have a java file having @Start, @End tag multiple places. looking for Regex which can replace the code between these two tag (including tag)

```
public class MyClass{ 
private String name; 
private String age; 

    @Start 
    private String address; 
    private String phoneNumber; 
    @End 
    -----------
    Some more code goes here
    ---------------

    @Start 
    private String pin; 
    private String amount; 
    @End 

    -----------
    Some more code goes here
    ---------------
}
```

I'm using google replacer plugin http://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/ and below configuration in maven pom to replace the content

```
<configuration>
..........
<token>@Start.*@End</token>
<value></value>
<regexFlags>
<regexFlag>DOTALL</regexFlag>
</regexFlags>
.......
</configuration>
```

I could replace the code between tag but it matches first @Start tag and last @End tag and removed everything between these two marker where as i want to replce the content only between two tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [non-greedy (or lazy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) operator

```
@Start.*?@End
```